# VS Code can't find name for "get" in Angular getter function, any ideas how to fix?

Tags: angular, authentication, visual-studio-code, auth0, getter

I'm an Angular newbie working on user authentication (IDE: VS Code) (using auth0 as authentication service). My problem is that when I try to use the function below, "get", "authenticated", and "boolean" all come up underlined in red, and I don't know what's going on. Basically, the function is supposed to check whether the parsed argument is true or not:

```
    get authenticated(): boolean {

      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this._authFlag) || '{}');

    }
```

VS Code tells me it cannot find the names "get" and "authenticated", which I'm assuming is leading to the error of boolean needing to be a type and not a value. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Here's the full component file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

//npm install --save @types/auth0-js (CLI cmd)
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

import{

  Observable,
  BehaviorSubject,
  bindNodeCallback, 
  of
} from 'rxjs';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({

    clientID: environment.auth0.clientID,

    domain: environment.auth0.domain,

    responseType: 'token id_token',

    scope: 'openid profile email'

  });

  //Track whether or not to renew token
  private _authFlag = 'isLoggedIn';
  
  private _userProfileFlag = 'userProfile';


  //Store authentication data & create stream for token
  token$!: Observable<string>;

  //Create stream for user profile data
  userProfile$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);


  //Authentication Navigation
  onAuthSuccessUrl = '/';

  onAuthFailureUrl = '/';

  logoutUrl = environment.auth0.logoutUrl;

  //Create observable of Auth0, then parseHash() function to gather 'auth' results
  parseHash$ = bindNodeCallback(this.auth0.parseHash.bind(this.auth0));

  //Create observable of Auth0 checkSession() function to verify authorization server session and renew tokens
  checkSession$ = bindNodeCallback(this.auth0.checkSession.bind(this.auth0));
  


  constructor(private router: Router) { 

    const userProfile = localStorage.getItem(this._userProfileFlag);

    if (userProfile) {

      this.userProfile$.next(JSON.parse(userProfile));

    }
  }

  login = () => this.auth0.authorize();
  

  handleLoginCallback = () => {

    if (window.location.hash && !this.authenticated) {

      this.parseHash$().subscribe({

        next: authResult => {
          this._setAuth(authResult);

          window.location.hash = '';

          this.router.navigate([this.onAuthSuccessUrl]);

        },

        error: err => this._handleError(err)

      });

    }

  };

  //Save authentication data and update login status subject
  private _setAuth = (authResult: any) => {

    //Observable of token
    this.token$ = of(authResult.accessToken);


    const userProfile = authResult.idTokenPayload;

    //Emit value for user data subject
    this.userProfile$.next(userProfile);

    //save 'userProfile' in 'localStorage'
    localStorage.setItem(this._userProfileFlag, JSON.stringify(userProfile));

    //Set flag in local storage stating that this app is logged in
    localStorage.setItem(this._authFlag, JSON.stringify(true));



    const renewAuth = () => {

      if (this.authenticated) {

        this.checkSession$({}).subscribe({

          next: authResult => this._setAuth(authResult),

          error: err => {

            localStorage.removeItem(this._authFlag);

            localStorage.removeItem(this._userProfileFlag);

            this.router.navigate([this.onAuthFailureUrl]);

          }

        });

      }

    }

    const logout = () => {

      //Set authentication status flag in local storage to false
      localStorage.setItem(this._authFlag, JSON.stringify(false));

      //remove the userProfile data
      localStorage.removeItem(this._userProfileFlag);

      //refresh, then redirect to homepage
      this.auth0.logout({

        returnTo: this.logoutUrl,

        clientID: environment.auth0.clientID

      });
      
    };

    get authenticated(): boolean {

      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this._authFlag) || '{}');

    }

  }

  
  //Utility functions
  private _handleError = (err: { error_description: any; }) => {

    if (err.error_description) {

      console.error(`Error: ${err.error_description}`);

    } else {

      console.error(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);

    }

  };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1**: `authenticated` getter placed in wrong place

From your code,

```js
private _setAuth = (authResult: any) => {
    ...

    get authenticated(): boolean {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this._authFlag) || '{}');
   }
}
```

**Solution for Issue 1**: Move out `authenticated` getter of `_setAuth` method.

```js
private _setAuth = (authResult: any) => {
    ...
}

get authenticated(): boolean {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this._authFlag) || '{}');
}
```

---

**Issue 2**: Duplicate variable name `authenticated` with getter `authenticated`.

You don't need to create variable while you have `authenticated` getter. Otherwise it is conflicted with variable name

**Solution for Issue 2**: Remove the variable declaration.

```js
authenticated!: boolean;
```

Comment: words can't express how grateful I am for your help! thank you so much!